# Want to logout the specific user, when admin inactive this specific user with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

***Want to logout the specific user, when admin inactive this specific user with Laravel***

```
public function userInactive1($id)
    {
        $selectedUser = User::find($id);
        if ($selectedUser) {
            // Update user status to inactive
            // $selectedUser->status = 0;
            $selectedUser->save();
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: See [ask], please. "I want" isn't a question, and the rest of your post lacks any indication of research, effort, attempts to solve, etc etc. We're happy to help people where needed but, as volunteers, we expect that you've made a reasonable attempt to work it out yourself first, and that you demonstrate this in your question. That sort of thing also tends to make your question more focused and more useful to future readers too. Thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ActiveUserCheck
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isActive()) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Your account is inactive. Please contact the administrator.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will logout the currently logged in user, not a user found by id. That's also invalid code. Also please don't just dump code as an answer, add some explanation of how this solves OPs question. Thanks

Comment: Want to just logout this "$selectedUser", Example admin will inactive the manager I mean "$selectedUser" than this "$selectedUser" will be autometically logout, If he login anywhere.

Comment: if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $id) {
    
            Auth::logout();
            // Invalidate the user's session
            request()->session()->invalidate();
            // Redirect to login page
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
@brombeer

Comment: this condition will be perform for current root user, I mean for example admin will inactive the manager in this time [Auth::user()->id is admin] and [$id is manager] than I want to just logout manager "$selectedUser"

Comment: @BhoopendraKumarYogi As with questions you can also edit your own answers and add updated code there. But ... the code you posted as comment here still would logout the currently logged in user - which is not what OP wants

Comment: $selectedUser = User::find($id);
    if ($selectedUser) {
        // Update user status to inactive
        $selectedUser->status = 0;
        $selectedUser->save();
        // Check if the logged-in user is the user being deactivated
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $id) {
            // Log out the user
            Auth::logout();
            // Invalidate the user's session
            request()->session()->invalidate();
            // Redirect to login page
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();

Comment: @BhoopendraKumarYogi Again, please edit your answer and post updated code there, not in the comments.

Comment: with this code specific user not loged out. 
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $id) {} this portion always not will be execute, Because Auth::user()->id and $id always be different.

Comment: we can use the middleware where we can check the auth and active status of the user.
if admin deActive any user from the admin than user will also logout while we check it through the middleware.

Comment: namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ActiveUserCheck
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isActive()) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Your account is inactive. Please contact the administrator.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

Comment: @BhoopendraKumarYogi you should mention that this is a middleware meant to protect your web routes from inactive users. Also mention how this middleware can be added to the routes/group ect

Comment: Protecting routes from inactive users is not what OP was asking for. This code will not logout a user with a given id

Answer (score -1):

```
If you need logout from the backend, when admin inactive this specific user  



public function logoutUserById($userId)
    {
        $user = User::find($userId);

        if ($user) {
            Auth::logoutOtherDevices($user->password);
            Auth::logout();
            // You can change the redirect URL according to your requirement 
            return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'User logged out successfully.');
        }
       // You can change the redirect URL according to your requirement 
        return redirect('/admin')->with('error', 'User not found.');
    }
```

Comment: `Auth::logout();` will logout the current authenticated user, not the user being deactivated